# Движок или самописный сайт

Tags: cms

На каком движке написан сайт ******, а так же его форум ********* возможно это как-то узнать по исходникам или это самописный сайт?

Comment: Судя по Wappalyzer, самописное с использованием ReactJS

Comment: Я б заподозрил на той стороне самописный продукт на NodeJS, т. к. явно имеет место серверный рендеринг React (а React на JS), а взаимодействие с клиентом происходит через довольно REST'овый API. Некоторые привычки намекают на Ruby on Rails, но это может быть прошлое разработчиков или прошлое разработчиков их инструментов.

Answer (score 3):

Можно узнавать используемую CMS с помощью сторонних ресурсов, например http://whatcms.org/ .

Так же опытный разработчик/пользователь CMS может узнать знакомые контейнеры/раперы/классы и т.п.

В данном случае сайт, вероятнее всего, самописный и CMS не использует.